# WIX toolset 3.11.2 preserve source files timestamps

Tags: wix, windows-installer, scheme, guile

I'm struggling to maintain file timestamps in MSI installer. I'm installing few scheme source files that needs to preserve their timestamps (Guile problems) and I can't figure way to do that.

Is there any way to stop Windows from adding [NOW] timestamps to my installed files?

Thanks

I tried "NeverOverwrite" but did not work at all

`<Component Id="cmp8671F140D78DA350C9F778C43791EAB1" Guid="{C27379FD-88AB-4630-98D0-AA2AC6FB42B8}" NeverOverwrite="yes"> <File Id="fil43915FF6E7931FF86F23DFCF40E79691" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.BasePath)\ide.cmd" /> </Component>`

BTW: Installer is not yet signed, is this might bea problem?

Comment: For the file timestamps I'd blame your build, because they get preserved fine for me. Folder timestamps, I don't think there's a native way. (Though I suppose it depends on the kind of timestamp)